# Summing historic cost rates over booked time (single effective date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a time management system where our employees or contractors (resources) enter the hours they have worked, and we derive a cost for it. I have a table with the historic costs:

```
CREATE TABLE ResourceTimeTypeCost (
 ResourceCode VARCHAR(32),
 TimeTypeCode VARCHAR(32),
 EffectiveDate DATETIME,
 CostRate DECIMAL(12,2)
)
```

So I have one date field which marks the effective date. If we have a record which is

```
('ResourceA', 'Normal', '2012-04-30', 40.00)
```

and I add a record which is

```
('ResourceA', 'Normal', '2012-05-04', 50.00)
```

So all hours entered between the 30th April and the 3rd of May will be at £40.00, all time after midnight on the 4th will be at £50.00. I understand this in principle but how do you write a query expressing this logic?

Assuming my time table looks like the below

```
CREATE TABLE TimeEntered (
 ResourceCode VARCHAR(32),
 TimeTypeCode VARCHAR(32),
 ProjectCode VARCHAR(32),
 ActivityCode VARCHAR(32),
 TimeEnteredDate DATETIME,
 HoursWorked DECIMAL(12,2)
)
```

If I insert the following records into the TimeEntered table

```
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-04-30',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-01',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-02',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-03',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-04',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-07',7.5)
('ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-08',7.5)
```

I'd like to get a query that returns the total cost by resource

So in the case above it would be 'ResourceA', (4 * 7.5 * 40) + (3 * 7.5 * 50) = 2325.00

Can anyone provide a sample SQL query? I know this example doesn't make use of TimeType (i.e. it's always 'Normal') but I'd like to see how this is dealt with as well

I can't change the structure of the database. Many thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to construct a view, CTE or subquery to find the most recent matching "resoucretimecost" record, and than {join,multiply,sum} with that.

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#ResourceTimeTypeCost') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ResourceTimeTypeCost
CREATE TABLE #ResourceTimeTypeCost (  ResourceCode VARCHAR(32),  TimeTypeCode VARCHAR(32),  EffectiveDate DATETIME,  CostRate DECIMAL(12,2) ) 
INSERT INTO #ResourceTimeTypeCost 
SELECT 'ResourceA' as resourcecode, 'Normal' as timetypecode, '2012-04-30' as effectivedate, 40.00 as costrate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ResourceA', 'Normal', '2012-05-04', 50.00

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TimeEntered') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TimeEntered
CREATE TABLE #TimeEntered (  ResourceCode VARCHAR(32),  TimeTypeCode VARCHAR(32),  ProjectCode VARCHAR(32),  ActivityCode VARCHAR(32),  TimeEnteredDate DATETIME,  HoursWorked DECIMAL(12,2) ) 
INSERT INTO #TimeEntered 
SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-04-30',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-01',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-02',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-03',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-04',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-07',7.5 
UNION ALL SELECT 'ResourceA','Normal','Project1','Management1','2012-05-08',7.5 

;with ranges as
(
select 
resourcecode 
,TimeTypeCode
,EffectiveDate
,costrate
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY resourcecode,timetypecode ORDER BY effectivedate ASC) as row
from #ResourceTimeTypeCost 
)
,ranges2 AS
(
SELECT 
r1.resourcecode 
,r1.TimeTypeCode
,r1.EffectiveDate
,r1.costrate
,r1.effectivedate as start_date
,ISNULL(DATEADD(ms,-3,r2.effectivedate),GETDATE()) as end_date
FROM ranges r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ranges r2 on r2.row = r1.row + 1 --joins onto the next date row
                    AND r2.resourcecode = r1.resourcecode 
                    AND r2.TimeTypeCode = r1.TimeTypeCode
)
SELECT 
tee.resourcecode
,tee.timetypecode
,tee.projectcode
,tee.activitycode
,SUM(ranges2.costrate * tee.hoursworked) as total_cost
FROM #TimeEntered tee
INNER JOIN ranges2 ON tee.TimeEnteredDate >= ranges2.start_date
                    AND tee.TimeEnteredDate <= ranges2.end_date
                    AND tee.resourcecode = ranges2.resourcecode
                    AND tee.timetypecode = ranges2.TimeTypeCode
GROUP BY tee.resourcecode
,tee.timetypecode
,tee.projectcode
,tee.activitycode
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution: it certainly gives me the right answer, but I can see I have a lot to learn on these "PARTITION BY"s. Is there a reason you've taken 3 milliseconds from the effectivedate? My instinct (had I somehow got this far!) would say change the join condition to <ranges2.end_date

Comment: @Jon I've removed the 3 milliseconds as this makes each start and end range completely unique (otherwise they will overlap), and 3ms is the smallest unit that the DATETIME data type can store.

Comment: Oh OK. Would I still be able to use an index on this if it was across (resourcecode, timetypecode, effectivedate)?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a cost table that is, as some would say, a slowly changing dimension.  First, it will help to have an effective and end date for the cost table.  We can get this by doing a self join and group by:

```
with costs as
    (select c.ResourceCode, c.EffectiveDate as effdate,
            dateadd(day, -1, min(c1.EffectiveDate)) as endDate,
            datediff(day, c.EffectiveDate, c1.EffectiveDate) - 1 as Span
     from ResourceTimeTypeCost c left outer join
          ResourceTimeTypeCost c1
     group by c.ResourceCode, c.EffectiveDate
    )
```

Although you say you cannot change the table structure, when you have a slowly changing dimension, having an effective and end date is good practice.

Now, you can use this infomation with TimeEntered as following:

```
select te.*, c.CostRate * te.HoursWorked as dayCost
from TimeEntered te join
     Costs c
     on te.ResouceCode = c.ResourceCode and
        te.TimeEntered between c.EffDate and c.EndDate
```

To summarize by Resource for a given time range, the full query would look like:

```
 with costs as
    (select c.ResourceCode, c.EffectiveDate as effdate,
            dateadd(day, -1, min(c1.EffectiveDate)) as endDate,
            datediff(day, c.EffectiveDate, c1.EffectiveDate) - 1 as Span
     from ResourceTimeTypeCost c left outer join
          ResourceTimeTypeCost c1
     group by c.ResourceCode, c.EffectiveDate
    ),
      te as
    (select te.*, c.CostRate * te.HoursWorked as dayCost
     from TimeEntered te join
          Costs c
          on te.ResouceCode = c.ResourceCode and
             te.TimeEntered between c.EffDate and c.EndDate
    )
select te.ResourceCode, sum(dayCost)
from te
where te.TimeEntered >= <date1> and te.TimeEntered < <date2>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might give this a try. [CROSS APPLY](http://riteshshah.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/cross-apply-and-outer-apply-clause-in-sql-server-2005/) will find first ResourceTimeTypeCost with older or equal date and same ResourceCode and TimeTypeCode as current record from TimeEntered.

```
SELECT te.ResourceCode,
       te.TimeTypeCode,
       te.ProjectCode,
       te.ActivityCode,
       te.TimeEnteredDate,
       te.HoursWorked,
       te.HoursWorked * rttc.CostRate Cost
FROM TimeEntered te 
CROSS APPLY
(
  -- First one only
  SELECT top 1 CostRate
    FROM ResourceTimeTypeCost
   WHERE te.ResourceCode = ResourceTimeTypeCost.ResourceCode
     AND te.TimeTypeCode = ResourceTimeTypeCost.TimeTypeCode
     AND te.TimeEnteredDate >= ResourceTimeTypeCost.EffectiveDate
   -- By most recent date
   ORDER BY ResourceTimeTypeCost.EffectiveDate DESC
) rttc
```

Unfortunately I can no longer find article on msdn, hence the blog in link above.

[Live test @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19d2c/5).

Comment: This is brilliant, I'll +1 you when I have the rep just for the SQL Fiddle link alone! In terms of the three solutions I've had, this is the one that appeals to the way my brain works the most. Is CROSS APPLY available in most flavours of SQL?

Comment: @Jon Thanks. Documentation says CROSS|OUTER APPLY is with us since 2005. Other solutions transform ResourceTimeTypeCost to range by joining it to itself and shifting by 1. Then it is trivial to find out in which range TimeEnteredDate belongs.